# PHP setCookie to subdomain not same subdomain in the front end

Tags: php

I'm setting a cookie from PHP using

```
 setcookie('test', 'hello', time()+10000, '/', 'test.domain.com', false);
```

For some reason, when I inspect the cookie from the front end, the domain is set to `.test.domain.com` instead of `test.domain.com` and I fail to understand why. Any idea ?

This makes it so to remove the cookie from JS, I have specify the same domain `.test.domain.com`. How do just set the subdomain from php without the added dot ?

Comment: Cookies are always inherited by subdomains, so it automatically adds the initial `.`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because PHP supports a deprecated format no longer required that needs the first dot.

Nothing to worry about.

> Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may
> require a leading . to match all subdomains. [php setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

**EDIT**: When removing the cookie, use the value `0` instead of `false`.

```php
setcookie('test', 'hello', time()+10000, '/', 'test.domain.com', 0);
```

Comment: The issue now is removing the cookie without specifically that same domain with the added dot...

Comment: There is a bug in devtools in updating the cookies ui with a leading dot. Close and reopen after testing the removal.